# What ability is raised by an imp familiar?

Tags: monsters, familiars, adnd-1e

the AD&D Monster Manual (p.54) states that if an imp is within 1 mile of the "master", he/she gains an additional level of ability. What ability are they referring to?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. I can answer this in a purely legal fashion, but how it actually works in play is another story! I hope another user can explain the mechanical ramifications of having—and losing!—an imp familiar. (E.g. does the amount of XP needed to advance a level vary depending on the closeness of the imp familiar?) No matter what, though, thank you for participating and have fun!

Answer (score 3):

> If the imp is
> within 1 mile its "master" gains an additional level of ability, but if the
> imp is over a mile distant the character loses 1 level, and if the familiar is
> killed the character drops 4 ability levels.

There’s nothing complicated here.

For example, for a 5th level magic-user:

- while the Imp is within 1 mile, they are a 6th level magic-user
- while the imp is further away, they are a 4th level magic-user
- if the imp dies, they are a 1st level magic-user

Proceed with caution.

Comment: Does the amount of XP needed for the "master" to advance a level vary then depending on the closeness of the imp familiar? Can the magic-user game his imp familiar's distance so that the magic-user can advance at an abnormal pace? In short, how do the rules handle the magic-user temporarily gaining and losing levels?

Comment: @HeyICanChan sounds like another question

Comment: @HeyICanChan (Not adding as an answer as not definitive.) Much of a magic-user's power is expressed via spells scaling with level e.g. Fireball does 1d6 per level of the caster. The easiest way to interpret the "gains/loses a level of ability" is to read it just as adjusting the casting level for spells, saving throws, attack rolls, but is otherwise the same level regarding to XP.

Comment: @Erics Sincerely, you're kind to offer me a recap, but my concern isn't how to interpret the imp's level gain/level loss feature but what the game actually says about level gain/level loss in places beyond the *Monster Manual*'s imp entry. If A asks B, "Do you have the time?" and B says *Yes*, that may be accurate but not as helpful as B saying *It's 8 AM*. This is a *Yes* answer, and I don't think it helps readers play the game better. I haven't downvoted it because it doesn't *hurt* anything, but I can't upvote it either. (Sorry, Dale M!)

Comment: @HeyICanChan but you haven’t asked “do you have the time”. At best you’ve asked “do you own a watch”, to which the answer “yes, I own three” is perfectly acceptable. This answer answers the question posed. If you want to know the answer to another question, ask it. There’s no charge for questions.